# Convert vector of dates to vector of days elapsed from first date

Tags: r, date

Given a vector 'dates', I would like to generate a new vector that counts the elapsed days since the first element.

```
dates <- c("2019-05-10", "2019-05-11", "2019-05-12", "2019-05-14", "2019-05-15", "2019-05-17")
```

Goal is: `elapsed_days <- c(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `lubridate` package, you can convert your dates in a date format and then perform regular calculation on it:

```r
library(lubridate)

ymd(dates)-min(ymd(dates))

Time differences in days
[1] 0 1 2 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = as.Date(dates)
as.double(dates - dates[1], units = "days")
#[1] 0 1 2 4 5 7
```